# MySQL Server Error Code - Can't change dr/ permission denied

Tags: mysql, wordpress, ubuntu, lamp

I had a LAMP stack running on Ubuntu for WordPress development, however something has gone wrong with the setup and I now get the infamous "**Error establishing a database connection**" when connecting to the localhost running WordPress. The problem is with MySQL; after executing a `killall` and restarting the related services, the MySQL restart fails. The error I get says:

```
Process: 2924 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

(...)

```
mysqld[2924]: mysqld" Can't change dir to '/var/lib/mysql/' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied).
```

I ran the commands both as the local user and as `sudo` so I don't know what's going on with the permissions. I gave the local user permissions over this directory through the `chown` command but that didn't change anything.

I can't figure out what went wrong with MySQL as the stack was running WordPress locally just fine. Then I came back from the weekend and poof - it's all a mess.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated; I really don't want to have to wipe the stack and start over. Thanks.